# MySQL - SELECT IN - Counting the # of rows for a user_id in a result?

Tags: mysql

I'm basically trying to query a table to see who might be gaming my paypal system.

The idea is I query my table to see what payments have failed, and then total up the number of failures by `user_id`. Pretty straightforward concept, I'm just really struggling on how to do it.

My start query:

```
SELECT * FROM `paypal_ipn` WHERE initial_payment_status =  'Failed'
```

I then want to use the above query, and just print out a total per `payer_id` (a column).

Is this possible in MySQL alone or do I need to use a PHP script?

Comment: Sorry, is it `payer_id` or `user_id`? I thought it was the latter, but if not, I'm afraid my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to do a sql `GROUP BY` operation. I couldn't tell from the question whether the data needs to be grouped by a column called `user_id` or `payer_id`. One of these queries should work for you:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) FROM `paypal_ipn`
WHERE initial_payment_status = 'Failed'
GROUP BY user_id;

SELECT payer_id, count(*) FROM `paypal_ipn`
WHERE initial_payment_status = 'Failed'
GROUP BY payer_id;
```

Comment: @Bohemian: Hehe, gotta be the quickest gun though!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Select payer_id, count(paypal_tranaction_id) from paypal_ipn where initial_payment_status = 'Failed' group by payer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group by on `user_id`. So the query would be look like:

`SELECT user_id, count(*) FROM paypal_ipn WHERE initial_payment_status =  'Failed' GROUP BY user_id;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this; I've added the total of failed payments to show you other interesting things you can query (I don't know if the payment is really called `payment`, mind).

```
SELECT payer_id,
    COUNT(*) AS transactions,
    SUM(payment) AS total
FROM `paypal_ipn` WHERE initial_payment_status = 'Failed'
GROUP BY payer_id;
```